# How can I get UserName or UserId from loginName control?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, userid

I'm wondering is there any way i could  get UserName or UserId for current User from LoginName control in ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) property of the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class:

```
string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Dear friend i said LoginName not login , LoginName doesn't have such this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could just read from Page.User.Identity.Name or HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.